# I can't install the game because "a problem occurred while trying to transfer the file"

Tags: technical-issues, the-sims-2

Each time I try to install *The Sims 2 Double Deluxe*, I usually get up to 7 or 8% installed until getting an error that says "A problem occurred when trying to transfer the file". Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image: Error prompt during installation of Sims 2 Double Deluxe]

Whenever I retry to copy the file, the same thing happens.
Also note that it's not always the `tv_network_talkshow.movie` file the problem occurs with.

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of problems are almost always problems with the installation disc. For example, a scratched disc will be unreadable where the scratch is. Because you get the error for different files, it's more likely to be dust, lint, fingerprints, or even tiny hairs on the disc. Cleaning the disc carefully with a soft cotton cloth may fix the problem.

Other software, such as antivirus programs, may be interrupting the disc read. Make sure no other unnecessary programs are running during the install, and consider temporarily disabling your antivirus program.

Another option is copying the disc contents to your hard disk and running the install from there. This will require at least 6gb of disk space.

Comment: If I wanted to copy the contents in the disc to my HDD, would that require making a Virtual Disc or something else? Explanation on how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: It would be like any other copy/paste process in the Windows File Manager. [This article](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/sims2-deluxe-install-help.97220/) describes how to do it, as well as a couple other things to try for this error. Supposedly, the information was taken from the Sims 2 website, but I couldn't find it. It may have been removed after Sims 3 or Sims 4 came out.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Wash the disk with warm water and mild soap. Use your finger to *lightly* (!) scrub it while it's soapy. Dry it and then rub plastic polish all over it, in tiny circles. When the polish begins to start drying, <strike>buff it</strike> remove the excess with the softest cotton T-shirt you have. I suggest, [Novus Fine Scratch Remover #2](http://www.retailresource.com/34824/Novus-Scratch-Remover-Smoothens-Surfaces.html?kpid=34824&gclid=CjwKEAjw3sKpBRDJ7rDqzsyuhDASJACZAikiHBJvWC5UDAxcUv34VSCp3uRXJGsTWZZMiQ5iETV9WhoCTt_w_wcB), as it's made for polishing acrylic.

Simply washing them gets most optical media working again.